# Add non-existent numbers with a zero value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office-2016

I have lot of **sequential** data in Excel.

The missing number in the sequence for Column A, should be populated with zero value in column B.
What formula i could use for this?

Data in excel sheet as below:

```
 A  | B
 0  | 4
 1  | 6
 4  | 4
 6  | 7
```

Expected output:

```
 A  | B
 0  | 4
 1  | 6
 2  | 0
 3  | 0
 4  | 4
 5  | 0
 6  | 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `B1` of your second table

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,original_table,2,0),0)
```

and drag down. Replace `original_table` with a reference to your first table